# Excel VBA column header instead of column number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel, and in VBA this bit of code:

```
If TableName(Y, 1) = "Dog" Then
```

Which works fine, it looks up the value of the first column and checks if it = "Animal"
But instead of using (Y, 1), I want to do it by declaring the column header instead of column number, eg: (Y, [AnimalHeader]), but this doesn't work, does anyone know is this is possible and how?

Comment: what about named ranges?

Comment: Yeh that could be one way, but Im surprised I can just reference to the header name like I can within the spreedsheet

Comment: Sorry, it's probably not what you want since you are using a table. However, what about a function to fetch the column, so that way you can use (Y, fetchColumn(Animal))

Comment: Isn't this just what `Match` is for?

Comment: @CLR you make a good point but Match can be wonky with strings

Comment: is `TableName` the name of a `ListObject` variable or what?

Comment: And what is `Y`? Some more context please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'wonky' @Yoav24 but for standard fieldnames I can't imagine many issues. If you were to build a `fetchColumn` function, it would likely just be a `Match` wrapped in some error trapping anyway..?

Comment: Yes TableName is ListObject. I am using TableName = Ws.ListObjects("TableName ").DataBodyRange

Comment: then `TableName` ISN'T a reference to a `ListObject` but to a `Range` object: to use the column name you must climb up to the `ListObject` level and exploit its `ListColumns` property

Comment: Is there a practical use for this exercise? If the intention is to "simplify" the syntax of writing code the approach is wrong, and if it has some bearing on what a user might enter somewhere a suitable approach would best be found by knowing the result the user is supposed to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get there quite that directly, I don't think, but this is close:

```
Dim lo as Excel.ListObject

Set lo =  Ws.ListObjects("TableName")
If lo.ListColumns("Animal").DataBodyRange(Y) = "Dog" Then ...
```

Comment: This was pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thanks!